# Keras - Save output of intermediate layer

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

**What I have done?**

I'm using from this code to implement my keras'model:

```
X, tx, Y, ty = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=np.random.seed(7), shuffle=True)

X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1]))
tx = np.reshape(tx, (tx.shape[0], 1, tx.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
filepath="weights-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=.20,
                    epochs=1000, batch_size=50, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=0)
```

**OUTPUT:**

Below is a part of the program's output:

```
Epoch 00993: val_acc did not improve
Epoch 00994: val_acc did not improve
Epoch 00995: val_acc did not improve
Epoch 00996: val_acc did not improve
Epoch 00997: val_acc did not improve
Epoch 00998: val_acc improved from 0.93900 to 0.94543, saving model to weights-998-0.94.hdf5
Epoch 00999: val_acc did not improve
```

**PROBLEM:**

I need to save the output of LSTM layer in any epoch but i do not know how?

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "output of the model"? ModelCheckpoint will save the weights for each layer of the model. How do you tell that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/models/model/). You will have to rewrite your model creation but it's not much work.  Then when you write something like this:

```
lstm_output = LSTM(128, ...)(x)
```

the output of the LSTM layer will be in the `lstm_output` variable and you can save it in every iteration of every epoch.

I hope this answers your question.